# In Spring Batch 3.0.x - How to set database type for Non-standard Database?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, annotations, batch-processing

Using the previous xml format, it can be achieved by following ways:-
(1)

```
<value>classpath:batch-mysql.properties</value>
```

(2)

```
<bean id="jobRepository" class="org...JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
<property name="databaseType" value="mysql"/>
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
```

[Reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureJob.html]

I was able to work with database using spring batch previous format xml. But I am stuck with the new format annotation. It is by default always using the embedded hsql.

But with the new format (using annotations only) how to set the database type?

There is not much information in the API document regarding this.

Could someone help me on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out couple of things. Figured out a way to achieve setting database type (May not be the efficient way). I am using -

```
HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
```

It is working. My code is available here - http://github.com/sidnan/spring-batch-example. If anyone got anything better please let me know. Thanks!